# Removing last character of each column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Imagin I have a output like this:

```
$ awk '{print $1,$5}'
    sample. sample1.
    test. test1.
```

The ideal output should be:

```
sample sample1
test test1
```

So I want to remove `.` at the end of **each column** .

Note these two columns are column number 1 and 5.

Comment: i don't know how awk prints the space before first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk '{gsub(/\./,"");print $1,$5}' file
```

But if you post the input file, it may be otter, better ways to do it.

---

To be more exact `remove . at the end of each column`

```
awk '{sub(/\.$/,"",$1);sub(/\.$/,"",$5);print $1,$5}' file
```

Comment: Although this may create OPs sample output, and OP seems happy with it, it is not a solution to what he actually asked for

Comment: @Jidder That is way I did ask for the original data, so all could be done nice and clean. And to answer correct what OP asks for: `awk '{sub(/\.$/,"",$1);sub(/\.$/,"",$5);print $1,$5}'`

Comment: @Jotne put that in your answer so if someone searches to delete the last character in columns they have the right answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with any character and `FS=" "` in awk, I would go for sed:

```
sed -e 's/. / /' -e 's/.$//'
```

This removes any last character before a space or end of line. Note `.` stands for any character, not only the dot.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
h.e. llo i. am here. and there
one two three four five six

$ awk '{print $1, $5}' a | sed -e 's/. / /' -e 's/.$//'
h.e here
on fiv
```

Comment: may i suggest to use `\.` instead of `.` and using this idea, using `[[:blank:][:cntrl:]]` instead of a single white space (ideal grouped with a `\1\`for replacment)

Comment: OK for the second suggestion, but for the first I am using `.` to match any character. Note the OP says: "remove last character", no matter which one it is. I will update later, thanks for the hint of `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: right for the `.`. the sample is a specific case where the title is like you say, sorry for writing this too fast :-)